# How to generate 3 integers which sum is 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to generate 3 random numbers which sum is 10.
It should show all possibilities.
It can work in procedure.

For example, it should look like:

```
exec AAA (3, 10)    
2+2+6    
1+3+6    
3+2+5    
7+1+2
```

The record of sum can not repeat.

The same question is for 2 random numbers like below:

```
exec AAA (2, 10)    
5+5   
4+6    
2+8    
3+7
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: This feels like it's a programmatical problem, not a set based one; why do you want (need?) to do this in T-SQL?

Comment: Is zero usable? What about decimal places? Negative numbers?

Comment: It is nice that you are telling us what you are trying to do. Good luck with that. Is that it? Or do you have a question?

Comment: Is 1+1+8 the same as 1+8+1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure below inputs a 2 or a 3 for the number of random numbers, and also inputs a Total number.  The stored procedure then outputs 2 or 3 random numbers that equal the Total.  All combinations of numbers are possibilities of the output.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GenerateNumbers
@Number INT,
@Total INT
AS

DECLARE @i INT = @Total
DECLARE @R1 INT
DECLARE @R2 INT
DECLARE @R3 INT

IF @Number = 2
BEGIN
    SET @R1 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (@Total + 1)) --0 through @Total
    SET @R2 = @Total - @R1
    SELECT CAST(@R1 AS varchar) + ' + ' + CAST(@R2 AS varchar)
END
ELSE IF @Number = 3
BEGIN
    SET @R1 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (@Total + 1)) --0 through @Total
    SET @R2 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (@Total - @R1 + 1))
    SET @R3 = @Total - @R1 - @R2
    SELECT CAST(@R1 AS varchar) + ' + ' + CAST(@R2 AS varchar) + ' + ' + CAST(@R3 AS varchar)
END
GO

EXEC GenerateNumbers 2, 10
EXEC GenerateNumbers 3, 10
```

Comment: This only gives 2 result, not many.

Comment: You can run EXEC GenerateNumbers 2, 100 to get 2 random numbers that equals 100.  If you run it again it will give you another 2 random numbers.  If you run EXEC GenerateNumbers 3, 523 then it will give 3 random numbers that add up to 523.  The OP asked to generate random numbers by running the stored procedure.

Comment: The OP states they want *all* the possibilities though.

Comment: I started off creating a procedure that returns ALL combinations, but then went back and re-read the original question, and noticed that random numbers are needed.

Comment: I noticed that too, so made the procedure generate any possible combination.  We can either generate random numbers OR generate every possible combination.  Since doing both isn't possible, I set it up so it generates random numbers where it can generate all possible combinations.

Comment: OP also gives an example of 4 random numbers for the output (so the stored procedure was executed 4 times), and didn't make the output return all combinations:    exec AAA (2, 10)    
5+5   
4+6    
2+8    
3+7

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a brute force approach which generates every possible combination.

```
Declare @Sum int = 10
Declare @Cnt int = 3  -- up to 6

;with cte as (
      Select Top (@Sum+1) N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
       From  master..spt_values n1
)
Select Distinct 
       SomeValue = concat(left(A1.N,10)
                          ,'+'+left(A2.N,10)
                          ,'+'+left(A3.N,10)
                          ,'+'+left(A4.N,10)
                          ,'+'+left(A5.N,10)
                          ,'+'+left(A6.N,10)
                         )
 From cte A1
 Left Join cte A2 on 1=1 and @Cnt>=2 -- essentially a conditional CROSS JOIN
 Left Join cte A3 on 1=1 and @Cnt>=3
 Left Join cte A4 on 1=1 and @Cnt>=4
 Left Join cte A5 on 1=1 and @Cnt>=5
 Left Join cte A6 on 1=1 and @Cnt>=6
 Where A1.N
      +coalesce(A2.N,0)
      +coalesce(A3.N,0)
      +coalesce(A4.N,0)
      +coalesce(A5.N,0)
      +coalesce(A6.N,0)
      = @Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't know *why* I'm answering this, but I felt like it anyway. I go down a dynamic SQL route, because that's the way I went... So be it. You'll need a Tally Function (I include the definition of mine here), and I *assume* SQL Server 2017+. No explanation given, just solution here (If you don't understand it, don't use it)

```sql
CREATE   FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@End bigint, @StartAtOne bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @StartAtOne = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (@End)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8)
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetAllTheSums @Numbers int, @Target int, @Debug bit = 0, @RunSql bit = 1 AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Numbers < 1 
        THROW 75624, N'Value of @Numbers parameter must be greater than 0',16;

    IF @Target < @Numbers
        THROW 75625, N'Value of @Target is impossible for given value of @Numbers.',16;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF NCHAR(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);


    SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM fn.Tally(@Target-@numbers+1,1) T1' + @CRLF + --We know we always need to first one
               (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'     CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'T',T.I)) + N'.I' + N',1) ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'T',T.I+1)),@CRLF)
                FROM fn.Tally(@Numbers-1,1) T) + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE ' + (SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'T',T.I)) + N'.I',' + ')
                            FROM fn.Tally(@Numbers,1) T) + N' = @Target;'
               
    IF @Debug = 1
        PRINT @SQL;
    IF @RunSql = 1
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Numbers int, @Target int', @Numbers, @Target;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.GetAllTheSums 3, 10;

EXEC dbo.GetAllTheSums 2, 12;

EXEC dbo.GetAllTheSums 4, 6, 1; 
GO

EXEC dbo.GetAllTheSums 7, 6;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a25ecc579e00ee4fd36ea25f19d45d3f)

For larger numbers, or more numbers, don't expect this to be fast, it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, for the fun of it...

With a CTE generating all numbers up to ten, you can write a recursive query that gives you all results for any given number of summands by cross joining again and again.

```
declare @numbers int = 3;

with numbers(number) as (select * from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(v))
, rec(str, sum, count) as
(
  select cast(number as varchar(10)), number, 1 from numbers
  union all
  select 
    cast(str + '+' + cast(numbers.number as varchar(2)) as varchar(10)), 
    sum + numbers.number,
    count +1
  from rec
  cross join numbers
  where count < @numbers and sum <= 10
)
select * from rec
where sum = 10 and count = @numbers;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74d96fcbf268484664bb79b2b59c4bb7

Comment: Your proposal is interesting. I try to understand it at all. The first time I encountered this: "rec(str, sum, count)". I see that you make th cross join between rec and numbers but I do not undestand there is "select cast(number as varchar(10)), number, 1 from numbers" and after "unino all". Could you break it down into factors? I try to no good effect.

Comment: `with rec(str, sum, count) as (...)` is a CTE. The name of it is `rec` and its columns are called `str`, `sum`, and `count`. This CTE is a recursive one, consisting of an anchor part, the `UNION ALL`, and the recursive part, in which the CTE references itself (`from rec`). Google "recursve query" or "recursive CTE" to find explanations on the net.

Comment: As to all those casts: I want to build a string like '1+2+7', so I must cast from number to string. The second `cast(...  as varchar(10))` is only necessary in SQL Server. It has problems with different lengths of strings in recursive queries.

Comment: The `with numbers(number) as (select * from (values ...))` is also only necessary because of a minor flaw in SQL Server by the way. In standard SQL this would merely be `with numbers(number) as (values...)`.

Comment: You should look at the other answers, too. You can learn a lot from them. And please answer the questions made in the request comments.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It is helpful. I noticed you use "count + 1". It is neccesary to catch the appropriate number of characters. But why does it work like that?

Comment: Have you looked up recursive queries? This is probably the most simple one. I count from 1 to 3.